# How can I use a promise to get the result of a SQLite-database transaction in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to check if a table in my SQLite database already exists.
can someone tell me how I can you promises to get the result value?

```
let tableCount = 0;

db.transaction(transaction =>
  transaction.executeSql(
    "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='methods';",
    [],
    (_, result) => {
      console.log(result.rows.length);
      tableCount = result.rows.length;
    },
    (err) => console.log("error")
  )
);

console.log(tableCount + "TEST");
```

So my problem is that the second console.log is executed before the first one and it still prints the value 0.

Comment: Put the second log inside the callback.

Comment: or convert callback to promise, you will find lots of resources of how to do that.

Comment: Thanks.Could you tell me how to do that? I'm new to javascript and quite unfamiliar with promises.

Answer (score 0):

I think its result is 0 at the moment , there are two ways :

```
async fetchData() {
  let tableCount = 0;

  await db.transaction(transaction =>
    transaction.executeSql(
      "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='methods';",
      [],
      (_, result) => {
        console.log(result.rows.length);
        tableCount = result.rows.length;
      },
      (err) => console.log("error")
    )
  );
  console.log(tableCount + "TEST");
}
```

Or you can use returned promise:

```
let tableCount = 0;

db.transaction(transaction =>
  transaction.executeSql(
    "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='methods';",
    [],
    (_, result) => {
      console.log(result.rows.length);
      tableCount = result.rows.length;
    },
    (err) => console.log("error")
  )
).then(() => {
  console.log(tableCount + "TEST");
});
```

Hope helps

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. But the first way gives me the same result and I already tried the second one but it says:
undefined is not an object (near '...}).then(function () {...')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I found a way to fix this by putting the code I want to execute depending on the result of the database transaction inside the result callback.